# SSMS Syntax Error Highlight

Tags: ssms, errors

In SSMS, a syntax error is highlighted with a red squiggly line. So is the `Invalid Object Name` error. In my mind, they’re two different things — the second can sometimes be rectified with Refresh Local Cache, but, obviously, the first can’t.

I can find settings for hundreds of things in the Options, but is there a setting which I can change to distinguish the two errors?